# Is there a word for an object which is utility based but beautiful?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

Perhaps this is a bit too unspecific but, is there an adjective which describes something built for a mechanical or technical purpose rather than for beauty, yet has a pleasant aesthetic appearance nonetheless? Perhaps somewhere in adjacency to utilitarian or pragmatic.

Comment: Functional yet elegant?

Comment: You could say it shows good _design_. that encompasses not only designing the object to function well, but to please the eye as well.  There are whole museums of industrial/commercial _design_, showing off fine examples of the fine art of _design_.

Answer (score 3):

You might describe it as being ***elegant***

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elegant) defines it as:

> Characterized by or exhibiting refined, tasteful beauty of manner, form, or style.

And [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elegant) as:

> 3. graceful in form or movement.
> 4. (of theories, solutions, computer programs, etc.) gracefully concise and simple; admirably succinct.